# Identify the op amp IC

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: unkown ic]

I am repairing a board, that has an IC labelled K72 J46 P.
I know it is an op amp MSOP8, and that pin 4 is GND, but I cannot find the manufacturer part number so that I can buy a replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an NCV20072 or NCS20072, which is a 3MHz dual rail-to-rail output op-amp.  Datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCS20071-D.PDF

For the record, this was found by searching for the string `"k72" top mark op amp`.  The datasheet shows that `K72` is the device-specific marking, `J46` is a date code (year and work week), `P` signifies the manufacturing location, and the dot indicates that the package is lead-free.

Comment: Thank you, it seem the exactly what i am searching for.